# PHP SimpleXML parsing not getting all attributes

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse an XML file, that was generated by a manufacturing equipment.
The XML file structure look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packagingOrderResult>
  <!-- parameters -->
  <par name="documentDate">2022-05-31</par>
  <par name="timestamp">2022-05-31 07:05:36</par>
  <par name="packagingLineNumber">01</par>
  <par name="ppo">000009374196_01</par>
  <par name="lotNumber">PW40069</par>
  <par name="matid">FP3572</par>
  <par name="expirationDate">2022-10-31</par>
  <par name="productionDate">2020-11-16</par>
  <par name="companyPrefix">50562411</par>
<!-- objects -->
  <objects>
    <!--default object level is 'boxLevel' (B)-->
    <!--default object state is 'OK' (1)-->
    <!--state 0 = 'Undefined'-->
    <!--state 1 = 'OK'-->
    <!--state 2 = 'NotOK'-->
    <!--state 3 = 'Sample'-->
    <obj idType="Sgtin" id="150127279064515DGB61WXAWADFX" level="B" status="2" />
    <obj idType="Sgtin" id="15012727906451RFY1W610481BZ2" level="B" status="2" />
    <obj idType="Sgtin" id="15012727906451V0Z2KMP9V91EAH" level="B" status="2" />
  </objects>
</packagingOrderResult>
```

I can read the file into array like so:

```
$parsed=simplexml_load_file($path.$file);
print_r($parsed);
```

and the results I get are:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [comment] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

        )

    [par] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2022-05-31
            [1] => 2022-05-31 07:05:36
            [2] => 01
            [3] => 000009374196_01
            [4] => PW40069
            [5] => FP3572
            [6] => 2022-10-31
            [7] => 2020-11-16
            [8] => 50562411
        )

[objects] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [comment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                )

            [obj] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [idType] => Sgtin
                                    [id] => 150127279064515DGB61WXAWADFX
                                    [level] => B
                                    [status] => 2
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [idType] => Sgtin
                                    [id] => 15012727906451RFY1W610481BZ2
                                    [level] => B
                                    [status] => 2
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [idType] => Sgtin
                                    [id] => 15012727906451V0Z2KMP9V91EAH
                                    [level] => B
                                    [status] => 2
                                )

                        )
                )
        )
)
```

As you can see the latter *objects* section gets parsed nicely with all the attributes into associated array (idType, id, level, status).
However the first section , the *par*, get parsed into a simple number-indexed array, ignoring the *name* attribute.

Bear in mind this is the first time that I ever had to deal with and parse XML files, so a lot of this is guess work. Is there are way to get the first part of that file into a nice associated array like the latter part of objects?

Comment: The first group the values are innertext while the second group the values are attributes.

Comment: Don't trust `print_r()` for this. SimpleXML objects are dynamically generated and they don't always serialise as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a debug output and will not include all data. That is why `json_encode($simpleXMLElement)` might not include all data of more complex XML, too.

The data is still here. How SimpleXML treats an element depends on how you access it.

```php
$packagingOrderResult = new SimpleXMLElement(getXMLString());

// loop over children with a specific element name
foreach ($packagingOrderResult->par as $par) {
    var_dump(
        [
            // access attribute using array access syntax
            'name' => (string)$par['name'],
            // cast to string to read text node child 
            'content' => (string)$par
        ]
    );
}

function getXMLString() {
  return <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packagingOrderResult>
  <!-- parameters -->
  <par name="documentDate">2022-05-31</par>
  <par name="timestamp">2022-05-31 07:05:36</par>
  <par name="packagingLineNumber">01</par>
  <par name="ppo">000009374196_01</par>
  <par name="lotNumber">PW40069</par>
  <par name="matid">FP3572</par>
  <par name="expirationDate">2022-10-31</par>
  <par name="productionDate">2020-11-16</par>
  <par name="companyPrefix">50562411</par>
<!-- objects -->
  <objects>
    <!--default object level is 'boxLevel' (B)-->
    <!--default object state is 'OK' (1)-->
    <!--state 0 = 'Undefined'-->
    <!--state 1 = 'OK'-->
    <!--state 2 = 'NotOK'-->
    <!--state 3 = 'Sample'-->
    <obj idType="Sgtin" id="150127279064515DGB61WXAWADFX" level="B" status="2" />
    <obj idType="Sgtin" id="15012727906451RFY1W610481BZ2" level="B" status="2" />
    <obj idType="Sgtin" id="15012727906451V0Z2KMP9V91EAH" level="B" status="2" />
  </objects>
</packagingOrderResult>
XML;
}
```